# No more involved in projects due to notice

Tags: resignation

My situation is as follows I'm a contractor working for a client. I have been here for over 2 years and I have taken a definite decision to leave.

I have about one month till my last day. The company requires working long hours. I have had small tasks left on my board which I extremely slowly fulfilled in past 2 weeks. I could finish all of them in one-two days.

There is a lot of new projects coming in but I feel that they do not want me to take part in it. On contrary my colleague is being fairly loaded with new very interesting stuff I would like to participate in.

I noticed that my managers do not include me in meetings anymore.

I am going to have a meeting with my manager this week where I am going to ask if I can help with something.

So far, while slowly fulling my tasks, in between, I started to learn new technologies and generally broadening my knowledge where I feel I will need it for my next challenges e.g. jobs.

Meanwhile an opportunity rose, where I am asked if could undertake a project (this is outside of the client or my company). I asked for specs and concluded that it would take 2 to 3 weeks of work.

I am hesitating if it is a good idea to take it and finish it during work hours. On one side this odd project would really gain me some experience that I need.

Answer (score 7):

Really what you are asking about is "What should I expect when I am leaving/in the leave period of my employment at a company?"

You are leaving in a month for another opportunity. The reality of your situation is that involving employees(even contractors) into a project is an investment for a company. An investment in time, effort and training to get that person up and running.

This investment pays off for the company in several ways. Not only do they gather the fruit of the employee's labor but they are also 'investing' interesting and fun work in employees as a bid to keep those employees around. The talented superstars of a department are going to tend to be given more 'fun' projects not just because they can handle them but also as an incentive to stick with the company. As an aside, ideally companies would always try to match workers with projects that dovetail with their interests and strengths, but that is not always possible given business needs and market demands.

So, from this, investing in you doesn't gain them anything. You've already put in your notice, you are already halfway out the door. What is the benefit to the company of you getting involved in what sounds like the early stages of a project - you won't be around to finish it, any decisions you make won't effect you, and the rest of the team has to be able to handle it without you there(which makes spreading training to you especially dangerous.) Finally if this is a potential business product for the company your involvement could result in a competitor or other company getting information about the product before it is public. So with all of these risks what are the benefits here? Well you get to work on interesting projects but you have no risks. They have all the risks but no real benefits.

So since they aren't giving you interesting projects what should you do?

First, even though you are not getting interesting projects you should absolutely NOT work on external or personal projects on company time or with company equipment. In many employment contracts anything you work on on company time or with company equipment may be partially or completely owned by that company. Even beyond that, though, is the fact that this is stealing from your employer. Yes it sucks that you're not being giving cool things to do but that does not excuse the theft of your time.

Second, you should talk to your supervisor. You shouldn't ask for a part in the new projects, you should ask what you can do to make the transition easier for everyone involved. Is your documentation up to date? Could another person come in and find the resources and tools you use/have made to do your job? This is how you maintain business relationships like this beyond the end of a job. If you skate out without cleaning up after yourself(ie just do personal projects, prep work for your new job, and avoid grunt or unfun work) you will be burning bridges at your current company.

Comment: Yes. Exactly This. If you have given notice, your responsibilities for the remaining time are (a) document your work so someone else can pick it up when you're gone, (b) train that person, (c) finish off anything that you have committed to completing within this time window, (d) finish off anything you promised to finish off, (e) whatever else management asks you to work on. IN THAT ORDER. You usually won't get to (e) -- both because it's usually lowest priority and because they know you're on your way out -- and may not even get to (d). You're a professional. Exit professionally.

Answer (score 4):

You told them you are a short timer. If they give you a task and you can't complete it in time, they may hurt their ability to deliver a project on time. Unless they are discussing a task assigned to you they no longer care about your ideas or opinions, so don't expect to get invited to many meetings.

They expect you to complete all your outstanding tasks, they may also expect you to document your position; adding tasks to your queue only will happen when everything else is done and they know a failure by you to complete a new task won't harm them.

Don't even think about doing outside work on their dime. This is especially true if you are still supposed to be completing tasks for them. Getting caught is a quick way to be sent home without pay, for the rest of the time you thought you were going to be working for them. It could also change your reason for leaving from quitting, to being fired.

Answer (score 2):

You decided to leave but want to be included on the cool new projects... It doesn't work that way. They'll probably leave you finishing up stuff you've been working on or even leave you without any work - there is no point bringing you in on a new project if you are leaving in a couple of weeks.

Ask your manager if you can help with anything else. Most likely he won't so feel free to read up on new technology etc.

Don't feel bad about your coworkers, they'll understand.